# Low Budget with AM1 vs FM2 vs LGA1151

Tags: motherboard, processor, memory

I'm building an extra PC, and for now I need purchase only a combo of motherboard + processor + memory.

(I know 4Gb RAM is low memory, I want later add more 4Gb RAM)

So, I did a research and I got the Configuration 01:
**Processor**: A4-7300 FM2
**Motherboard**: AMD FM2A58M-VG3+
**Memory**: 4GB DDR3 1600MHz
**Total**: $ 145,00 USD

The Configuration 2 is:
**Processor**: Athlon 5150 AM1
**Motherboard**: ASRockAM1B-MH
**Memory**: 4GB DDR3 1600MHz
**Total**: $ 135,00 USD

and finally, the Configuration 3:
**Processor**: Pentium Dual Core G4400 LGA1151
**Motherboard**: ASRockH110M-HG4
**Memory**: 4GB DDR4 2400MHZ
**Total**: $ 215,00 USD

**EDIT**: Too broad?
Really, really simple question then:
**What of that 3 configurations have the best cost-benefit** (considering what I'll be using them for) **and why?**

**Operational System:**
*Windows 10 AU*

**Games** (can be played at minimum level of graphics):
*Hearthstone, League Of Legends, Stacraft 2*

**Applications:**
*Visual Studio 2017, Sql Server 2016, Bluestacks, LibreOffice*

**Rarely used:**
*Some VM like VirtualBox or VMWare*

Comment: If I know that things, I can tell some sample answers, like (1) AM1 is bad for gaming because is a soc (sytem on a chip), and this put him as better/worse than any FM2 counterpart, (2) The Intel config is 75USD go with AMD because the performance of the processors is similar (3) AM3+ is for TOP AMD processors, forget in this low budget comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM1 is not the best for gaming due to being an older technology with less capable CPUs, FM2 is newer. Personally, I'd go with the FM2 system, it is a more powerful CPU, and has built in graphics capability.  It also meets the minimum CPU speed and graphics requirements for the games you have listed. Though it will likely not be able to handle cutting edge gaming at max settings, without major upgrades.